# Syncfusion HtmlToPdfConverter - different margins per page

Tags: c#, pdf, syncfusion

I'm trying to convert an HTML page to a PDF document using Syncfusion with the Blink rendering engine.

I want to use different margins for different pages. (All pages must have margins, except for the first page which must have no margins.)

Is this possible? Or can I only specify one margin that's used on all pages?

```
var sy = new Syncfusion.HtmlConverter.HtmlToPdfConverter();
sy.RenderingEngine = HtmlRenderingEngine.Blink;

var blinkSettings = new BlinkConverterSettings
{
    ViewPortSize = new System.Drawing.Size(912, 0)
};
blinkSettings.Margin.All = 0;

sy.ConverterSettings = blinkSettings;
var document = sy.Convert(sourceUrl);
```

Comment: Indeed, our HTML page is set up as one big page, so we can't add content for page-specific margins there. Another PDF tool, HiQPdf, actually supports changing the margins for each individual page, but unfortunately we have other issues with that tool and it seems they're out of business...